# 15.04 boots without unity or menu

Tags: unity, 15.04, compiz, launcher

Was composing an email when notification of disconnection from wifi appeared. Couldn't reconnect wifi.

I saved the email and rebooted to a black band across the bottom of the desktop wallpaper with Docky launcher in front of it, and no main system menu. I could launch apps from Docky, but no window controls visible. I've since reset Docky not to start on boot and can't launch anything now.

I have one folder on the desktop which I can open with the mouse, but there are no window controls (I can use Alt-F4 to close windows). Ctl-Alt-T doesn't work, but I can right-click the desktop and start a Terminal session.

I have installed ccsm and re-enabled Unity plugin and OpenGL, but still no launcher or main menu.

Answer (score 0):

I kept on searching and found some further info and tried ccsm again. It worked this time. I don't know why it worked this time and not the other times. Anyway, I have my familiar desktop back.